# Add server params on PWA push notification

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to add custom title, body, etc. from server params on `showNotification` method ?

```
var title = 'My title';

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: 'My body',
      icon: 'images/icon.png',
      tag: 'my-tag'
    }));
```

I use an classic Firebase for stock my user token. For example, on new article, send the article title.

Comment: I think you need to follow the specified parameter in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/). `showNotification()` expects a `title` and we can give it an `options` object. You may also check this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) for additional reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can show custom push notifications using data from server, which applies to your use case as well. These notifications can be shown even with your app is not actively used by the user. Like how you receive deals notifications from Amazon app, you can show your new article title and body by getting data from the server using an push event listener like below and use that data to phrase and use it on different parts of your notification.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {
  var body;

  if (e.data) {
    body = e.data.text();
  } else {
    body = 'Push message no payload';
  }

  var options = {
    body: body,
    icon: 'images/notification-flat.png',
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      primaryKey: 1
    },
    actions: [
      {action: 'explore', title: 'Explore this new world',
        icon: 'images/checkmark.png'},
      {action: 'close', title: 'I don't want any of this',
        icon: 'images/xmark.png'},
    ]
  };
  e.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification('Push Notification', options)
  );
});
```

For more description, look at **Receiving Data in the Service Worker** section of [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications).